# Publicaciones en tiempo real - Firestore - Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

una consulta, espero me puedan ayudar.
Estoy usando firebase para mi proyecto de la U, el problema que tengo es: ¿Como puedo traer todos los documentos que los usuarios publican de acuerdo a su gmail, para que todos estos documentos se vean en tiempo real en todos los usuarios logueados?

Este es el código que uso para subir a firestore

```
db.collection("Users").document(email).collection("Publicaciones").document()
            .set(datos)
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Void aVoid){
                    mProgressDialog.dismiss();

                    limpiarCeldas();

                    Toast.makeText(Formulario.this, "Publicado exitosamente", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    //Intent intent = new Intent(Formulario.this, MainActivity.class);
                    //startActivity(intent);

                    finish();

                }
            })
            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(Formulario.this, "No se pudo realizar la operación", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            });
```

Y se muestra así en firebase:

[image]

Como pueden ver, hay 2 usuarios logueados con gmail y cada uno de ellos tienen diferentes publicaciones.
Ahora quisiera traerlos en tiempo real y estoy usando .addSnapshotListener, este es el código que estoy usando:

```
  db.collection("Users").document(google.getEmail()).collection("Publicaciones").addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot value, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException error) {
            ArrayList<NoticiaModel> noticias = new ArrayList<>();
            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : value) {

                NoticiaModel model = document.toObject(NoticiaModel.class);

                model.setTitulo(model.getTitulo());
                model.setUser(model.getUser());

                noticias.add(model);

            
            }

            AdapterRecyclerView adapterRecyclerView = new AdapterRecyclerView(noticias, R.layout.cardview_picture, getActivity());
            noticiasRecycler.setAdapter(adapterRecyclerView);
        }
    });
```

Como pueden ver solo estoy trayendo de acuerdo al documento de cada usuario, pero quisiera traer todos los documentos existentes para que puedan ver todos los usuarios logueados.

Este es otro código de prueba que hice para ver si traía todos los documentos:

```
prueba.collection("Publicaciones")
            .orderBy("tiempo", Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
            .addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot value,
                                    @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {

                    if (e!=null){
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Error" + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }else {
                        ArrayList<NoticiaModel> noticias = new ArrayList<>();
                        for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : value) {

                            NoticiaModel model = document.toObject(NoticiaModel.class);

                            model.setTitulo(model.getTitulo());
                            model.setUser(model.getUser());

                            noticias.add(model);

                        }

                        AdapterRecyclerView adapterRecyclerView = new AdapterRecyclerView(noticias, R.layout.cardview_picture, getActivity());
                        noticiasRecycler.setAdapter(adapterRecyclerView);
                    }

                }
            });
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ese código me traía todos los documentos, pero los documentos eran generados automáticamente y no así por su gmail.

Espero me puedan ayudar, gracias!!!

Comment: a que te refieres con que los documentos son generados automaticamente ? en la segunda foto que tienes, tienes un correo por cada publicacion, cual seria el problema de la segunda aproximacion ?